# Como atualizar uma tabela através do AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Ola. Eu gostaria de, ao clicar em "cadastrar" na div "cadastro-clientes" fosse atualizada a tabela de clientes na div "md-clientes", mas nao sei como fazer com que a tabela atualize sem atualizar o html todo.

DIV cadastro-clientes:

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="cadastro-clientes">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5>Cadastro de clientes</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form method="POST" id="cad-form" name="cad-form" action="cadastro.php">
              <div class="form-group cad-container">
                <label>Qual o nome completo?</label>
                <input class="form-control" name="nome" placeholder="Nome e sobrenome">
                <label>E a data de nascimento?</label>
                <input inputmode="numeric" name="data_nasc" class="form-control um" id="cad-dat-nasc" placeholder="Ex: 01/01/2020">
                <label>Qual o telefone? </label>
                <input inputmode="numeric" name="telefone" class="form-control um" id="cad-tel"placeholder="Ex: (99) 9 9999-9999">
                <label>Onde mora? </label>
                <input class="form-control" name="endereco" placeholder="Rua, numero, bairro e cidade">
                <label>Qual o CPF?</label>
                <input inputmode="numeric" name="cpf" class="form-control um" id="cad-cpf" placeholder="Ex: 999.999.999-99">
                <label>E o RG?</label>
                <input inputmode="numeric" name="rg" class="form-control um" id="cad-rg"placeholder="Ex: 99.999999-9">
              </div>
              <!--o cad-btn deve estar dentro do formulario-->
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="volta-btn">Voltar</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="cad-btn">Cadastrar</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

div md-clientes:

```
  <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="md-clientes">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header clientes-container">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <h5>Pesquisar clientes</h5>
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control center" placeholder="Informe o nome">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <!--tabela clientes-->
          <div class="modal-body">
            <!--tabela clientes-->
            <div data-spy"scroll" data-target="modal-body" data-offset="0" class="scroll-height">
              <div class="bd-example">
                <div class="table-responsive-lg">
                  <table class="table table-striped" id="tabela-clientes">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="col">ID</th>
                        <th scope="col">Nome</th>
                        <th scope="col">Telefone</th>
                        <th scope="col">CPF</th>
                        <th scope="col">RG</th>
                        <th scope="col">Endereço</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <!-- laco de repeticao de clientes -->
                      <?php
                        include("cadastro.php");
                        $grupo = exibirClientes(); ?>

                        <?php
                        foreach($grupo as $dados){
                        ?>
                          <tr>
                              <td><?=$dados["nome"] ?> </td>
                              <td><?=$dados["dataNascimento"] ?> </td>
                              <td><?=$dados["telefone"] ?> </td>
                              <td><?=$dados["cpf"] ?> </td>
                              <td><?=$dados["rg"] ?> </td>
                              <td><?=$dados["endereco"] ?> </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="md-cadastro">Cadastro</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Deletar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

javascript (ajax):

```
$('form[name="cad-form"]').submit(function(){
  var dados = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'cadastro.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: dados,
      success:function(data){
        if (data == "sucesso") {
          alert("Cliente cadastrado com sucesso! :)");
          }
          /*caso nao retorne "sucesso", mas realiza o cadastro, retorna oq houve
            de errado*/
          else {
            alert(data);
          }

        }
    })
    // "trava" o submit
  return false;
})
```

Obrigado desde já e tenham um ótimo dia!

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi, quer que ao cadastrar um novo item ele apareça automaticamente na div sem precisar atualizar?

Comment: Isso mesmo! No caso atual, o item so aparece na tabela quando atualiza o html

Answer (score 0):

Você deve usar a função "append()" do jquery para adicionar os itens que vem do teu formulario na div do html

```js
let nome = "";
let dataNascimento = "";
let telefone = "";
let cpf = "";
let rg = "";
let endereco = "";

let tr = `<tr>
            <td>${nome}</td>
            <td>${dataNascimento}</td>
            <td>${telefone}</td>
            <td>${cpf}</td>
            <td>${rg}</td>
            <td>${endereco}</td>
          </tr>`;

$("body #tabela-clientes tbody").append(tr)
```

nas variáveis, você coloca os dados que vem do formulário, e assim que finalizar a requisição os itens serão adicionados (append) ao final da sua DIV. Assim...

```js
$('form[name="cad-form"]').submit(function(){
  var dados = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'cadastro.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: dados,
      success:function(data){
        if (data == "sucesso") {
        
            let nome = "nomeQueVemDoForm";
            let dataNascimento = "datadeNascQueVemDoForm";
            let telefone = "telefoneQueVemDoForm";
            let cpf = "cpfQueVemDoForm";
            let rg = "rgQueVemDoForm";
            let endereco = "enderecoQueVemDoForm";

            let tr = `<tr>
                        <td>${nome}</td>
                        <td>${dataNascimento}</td>
                        <td>${telefone}</td>
                        <td>${cpf}</td>
                        <td>${rg}</td>
                        <td>${endereco}</td>
                      </tr>`;

            $("body #tabela-clientes tbody").append(tr)

        }
          /*caso nao retorne "sucesso", mas realiza o cadastro, retorna oq houve
            de errado*/
          else {
            alert(data);
          }

        }
    })
    // "trava" o submit
  return false;
})
```